# One who objectifies women

Tags: single-word-requests, semantics, pejorative-language

Is there a single word or short phrase to describe someone who treats women like objects?
Is there a similar word/phrase for who objectifies other people in general?

Comment: Jackie Treehorn.

Comment: An 'objectifier' in general would probably best be called a **psychopath**. **Autist** if you wanted to downplay the negativity a bit, but that's not a word with any real currency. But you'll be swamped by Answers focusing on satyriasis and its associated lack of consideration for *women*, rather than the inability to recognise other *people* as sentient beings with 'rights'.

Comment: @Fumble: Autist probably isn't appropriate here. I don't think the OP is looking for a diagnoses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some thoughts:
[misogynist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misogyny)
[(male) chauvinist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinist?show=0&t=1304370386)
[sexist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sexist)

None really encompasses the objectification of women, but they all kind of get at the idea.

Comment: I had considered "misogynist," but the character in question does not hate women, per se; quite the opposite, in fact.

Answer (score 5):

**Objectifier** fits your second question.  Add "of women" if that's short enough to answer the first.

I've heard **womanizer** used that way as well, although it's not exactly the same as the formal definition.

Comment: To add to this, [objectification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_objectification) is the appropriate technical term with strong similarities with [dehumanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehumanization).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of words that come to mind to describe someone who objectifies women, but there are so many nuanced responses that it is hard to pin down just one.  Here are a few that come to mind, many of the definitions contain other possible words to describe an objectifier:

For the kind of person that objectifies women "for amorous sport," these apply:

***Don Juan***

> a ladies' man; womanizer.

***Casanova***

> a man with a reputation for having many amorous adventures; rake.

Along the same lines: ***libertine***, ***rake***

If the person eying the other is doing so from afar, then ***ogler*** could work:

> one who looks at amorously, flirtatiously, or impertinently.

*all definitions are from [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/)*

Answer (score -1):

How about **Hetaerism / Hetaerist**?

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hetaerism):

> **hetaerism, hetairism**
>
> 1. the practice of concubinage.
> 2. a social system characterized by its regarding women as common property.
>
>    — hetaerist, hetairist, n. — hetaeristic, hetairistic, adj.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetaerism):

> **Hetaerism** or **hetairism** can mean:
>
> ...
>   Women were the common property of
>   their tribe, and the children never
>   knew their fathers. Sometimes known
>   as "primitive promiscuity"

Comment: I assume the reason for this answer being marked down is that the words you have suggested do not appear in more official dictionaries (OED for example). It is a development of the term 'hetaera', which refers to the *women* in question. While that is valid grounds for dismissing this answer, it's a shame because if they were words, I think they would answer this question quite well.