# Is there a term for "hatred of women" besides misogyny?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

The reason I ask is that [at least one dictionary definition](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/10/17/us-australia-misogyny-idUSBRE89G0D520121017) incorporates two meanings for misogyny: "hatred of women" and "entrenched prejudice against women".

I want a term that means "hatred of women" but cannot be mistaken for this "entrenched prejudice against women" sense. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/misogynist does not produce anything acceptable, but I am not necessarily looking for a one-word term - it can be a phrase. However, I am looking for a term that is not "misogyny" or "hatred of women".

Comment: What's wrong with *hatred of women* as a phrase? That's pretty much unequivocal.

Comment: I'm sure context will establish whether the author is speaking about a loathing of women or expressing his prejudicial views. It's quite common for terms to have more than one meaning.

Comment: related: 1. [One who objectifies women](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23548/one-who-objectifies-women) 2. [Word for “Woman Who Hates Men”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130090/word-for-woman-who-hates-men) 3. [Word that denotes the belief that women are inferior to men](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61187/word-that-denotes-the-belief-that-women-are-inferior-to-men/61190#61190)

Comment: Please don't hate me.

Comment: Can you provide a context? Hate and inveterate prejudice often go hand in hand.

Comment: The context is that I'm correcting an essay about someone who has been accused of prejudice against women and another person who has been accused of hating women. The latter person may also be prejudiced against women, but nobody thinks that the former person hates women.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include this *very* important distinction. EDIT: You want to say someone *doesn't* hate women, but they are prejudiced against them? This is quite a different question.

Comment: My question is correct as written. It is in the general context of marking a student essay that I'm called on to explain distinctions between these terms. The context is quite irrelevant to my question, but I explained it because I was asked about it.

Comment: By providing context you are give users more information thereby supplying you with better answers. That is in your best interest. I asked what was wrong with "hatred for women," which you never answered; however,  if the topic is sexual discrimination then the term *misogynist* will be understood (by some) within that context.  Context will help users and their answers will help you.

Comment: I think you can get by with _misogyny_. While it may also mean prejudice, the word _sexism_ seems to have mostly replaced it for that sense. Whenever I hear of a misogynist, I think of someone who hates women and treats them badly.